# Looking for a phrase for looking

Tags: phrases

See the photo: 
http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Film/Pix/pictures/2011/3/30/1301471878380/The-Three-Musketeers-007.jpg

What's the most elegant way of describing the way they face the three different directions? I'd like to begin with:

***They're standing there....***

facing each of the three directions?
looking at the three directions?
**____________________________**?

Comment: And, are there not four?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Facing outward" perhaps?

I might also say "facing three ways", but "outward" seems more apt as it encompasses the idea that they're in a group and facing away from it, rather than just randomly looking at different things, or not looking at each other.

Comment: Or back-to-back would probably work, even with a group.

Answer (score 0):

> **[Trifarious](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trifarious)**  facing in three different directions

The use of trifarious meant "in three parts" as early as 1817. Presently it has a botanical connotation and I have yet to find 'trifariously' used in any other context. I suspect there may be a dance related term that describes their triangular dos-à-dos position but I would say 'the fighters were standing in a trifarious defensive position